# dropdown menu not opening and closing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have gotten it to open and close when hovering over the nav link but how do I keep it open so I can access the content on the menu? I need it to work exactly how a dropdown menu works.

This is what I have done so far I also need the html layout to stay the same.

```js
$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseover(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link">home</li>
    <li class="nav-link--dropdown">dropdown</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
    <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq41y2kz/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should remove margin use padding for that, if not when we enter that margin area mouse leave event will trigger.

[image]

```js
$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseover(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.dropdown-menu').mouseover(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});

$('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-link">home</li>
        <li class="nav-link--dropdown">dropdown</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
        <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
        <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that you leave the nav-link--dropdown when you move to your dropdown-menu. The simple solution: Include your dropdown-menu in your nav item.

```js
$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseover(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.nav-link--dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu ul {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link">home</li>
    <li class="nav-link--dropdown">
     dropdown
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
          <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by bundling the menu item you want to hover over and it's dropdown in the same div.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-link">home</li>
    <div class="innerNav">
        <li class="nav-link--dropdown">dropdown</li>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
              <li class="dropdown-menu__link">random text</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And:

```
$('.innerNav').mouseover(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.innerNav').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmdfqh6c/

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is the `mouseleave` event will trigger when you try to move the mouse to the bellow dropdown menu, if you really must keep the elements separated, add the dropdown-menu to the class that keeps the display:block

```
$('.nav-link--dropdown, .dropdown-menu').mouseover(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.nav-link--dropdown, .dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');
});
```

And remove margin/padding from menu items. Use line-height instead if you want some spacing:

```
.nav ul li {
  line-height: 40px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;  // <--- I changed this from padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Otherwise the other suggested solutions to include the dropdown within you parent `<ul>` element is the best.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjw1a3op/)